# How to change version of application in air package?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, adobe

I need to change version of air package from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0, without having it's source codes.

I've tried to extract .air package with winRar, and changing the META-INF\AIR\application.xml file, then after archiving it back to .air package, install it, but it gives me an error - "package cannot be install, try to get new file".

Any ideas how to change information in .air file? OR how to make auto update to older version of application?

Answer (score 0):

Every AIR application requires an application descriptor file. The application descriptor file is an XML document that defines the basic properties of the application.

Open your -app.xml in your adobe air application project and change value in version tag

```
<versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I haven`t source codes. I need to change version of already compilied air package.

Comment: Not possible, Recompile!

Comment: For Adobe Air application
find path `META-INF\AIR` in your application's installed directory. where you can find a file name `application.xml`. this file have <versionNumber> tag, Change its number and you can see that version of application is changed